# React child JSX element not inheriting this from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

it feels like my question is pretty simple but I can't work out why it's not working.

Why I'm trying to do is basic stuff - I'm passing a function from parent to child that it supposed to increment a value (thats just a proof of concept) of parent's "test" value by 1. The problem occurs when the parent's function is called. I'm getting 'Cannot read property test of undefined". In debugger this.props is also undefined, so no surprise that this.props.test will be. What am I missing?

Parent:

```
export default class GameList extends Component {
  constructor({ navigation }) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      test: 0,
    }
  };


  updateState() {
    this.setState({
      test: this.state.test++,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.background}>
        <Header updateState={this.updateState} />   
     </View >
    )
  }
}
```

Child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.props.updateState();
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  filterRows(searchText, dataSet) {
    return dataSet.filter((record) => record.title.includes(searchText));
  }
}


export default Header;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

- bind the method in your constructor to give it the correct context. More information about why this is necessary is in the [React documentation under *Handling Events*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html).
- do not use `++` on state properties because it modifies the original state and possibly defeats any comparisons when checking whether to re-render (i.e. Is `this.state.test === newState.test`? Yes, because the original has been altered). There is more information in this under the [React documentation under *Component*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), note how they use `quantity: state.quantity + 1` rather than `quantity: state.quantity++`

So instead you get:

```
export default class GameList extends Component {
  constructor({ navigation }) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      test: 0,
    }
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this); // Bind to the correct context
  };


  updateState() {
    this.setState({
      test: this.state.test + 1, // Do not mutate the original state
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.background}>
        <Header updateState={this.updateState} />   
     </View >
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your parent constructor you need to bind the function properly.

This is what it could look like:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  this.state = { test: 0 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` context is no longer bound when the `this.updateState` function is called, to do this you could use the arrow function (which set's the `this` context to the current context)

See more info about arrow functions and the this context [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.background}>
      <Header updateState={() => this.updateState()} />   
   </View >
  )
}
```

Comment: You're all correct guys ;) I didn't know that by just passing the function as a param in parent element I'm not passing the context - the wrapping with arrow function suits me the most as I'm using ES6 but that bind method is also working as expected. I've also changed the setState to set the value based on prevState argument, it's all working great now! +1 to all of you and star for the ES6 solution!

Comment: @grovesNL any reason why when I pass an argument in the childs element: this.props.updateState(filteredResults) - the argument is not being passed to the parents function? In Parent I've got   updateState(filteredResults) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(filteredResults),
    }));
  }

Comment: @MTM You have to pass the parameters along in the arrow function version

Answer (score 0):

Corrected, working example based on answers above:

Parent:

```
export default class GameList extends Component {
  constructor({ navigation }) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      test: 0,
    }
  };

  updateState() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      debugger;
      return ({
        test: prevState.test + 1,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.background}>
        <Header updateState={() => { this.updateState() }} />      
      </View >
    )
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.props.updateState();
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default Header;
```